# oracle count records daily join

Tags: oracle, join, calendar

Gurus, (Oracle 12c)
I am having a difficult time getting a daily count of records for multiple tables.  The base of the query I think should be a calendar.  I have create a calendar as the following:

```
with calendar as(select rownum -1 as day from dual
connect by rownum < sysdate - TO_DATE('2020-08-01')+1)
select to_date('2020-08-01')+ day as sale_date from calendar
```

Source table:

```
CREATE TABLE "CARS1" 
   (    "COUNT_CARS" NUMBER(10,0), 
"EQUIPMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"LOCATION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"SALE_DATE" DATE) 
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

CREATE TABLE "CARS2" 
   (    "COUNT_CARS" NUMBER(10,0), 
"EQUIPMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"LOCATION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"SALE_DATE" DATE) 
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

DML Script:

```
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION,SALE_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-05 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('9', 'Jaguars', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-05 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('7', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-04 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('10','Trans Am', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS1" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('4', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION,SALE_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('9', 'Jaguars', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('7', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-03 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('10','Trans Am', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-03 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2020-08-03 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CARS2" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_DATE) VALUES ('4', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

I can simply get the count of cars from 1 table without using the calendar as a base for the results, but I can't figure out how to make the calendar day as the base and join multiple tables to get a daily count of cars from that table (lets say adding 40 tables to get the daily counts on each against each day).

Result would look like:

```
#SALE_DATE #  cars1  cars2
2020-08-01    12      4
2020-08-02    0       17
2020-08-03    0       25
2020-08-04    7       0
2020-08-05    17      0
```

Comment: sorry for format issues

Comment: I did the formatting. just check if all is ok

Comment: thank u, sorry new to this

Comment: I know I can get the results without a calendar for 1 table: select trunc(sale_date),count(*) from cars1 group by trunc(sale_date) order by trunc(sale_date) desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task appeared to be a bit harder as I thought in the beginning. This is how you can get the result you needed

```
with calendar as(select level + to_date('2020-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - 1 day 
                   from dual
                connect by level + to_date('2020-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') < to_date('2020-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
     c1_sales as (select sale_date, sum(count_cars) count_cars from cars1 group by sale_date),
     c2_sales as (select sale_date, sum(count_cars) count_cars from cars2 group by sale_date)

select c.day, nvl(t1.count_cars, 0), nvl(t2.count_cars, 0)
  from calendar c,
       c1_sales t1,
       c2_sales t2
 where t1.sale_date(+) = c.day
   and t2.sale_date(+) = c.day
 order by c.day;
```

Thanks for a tricky question - it was interesting to solve

Comment: I know, I thought I would challenge myself, but I could not figure out how to approach it.  I know this will be helpful to many users- thank u Ekochergin.  I am trying out the logic

Comment: i am getting ora error- expected number got timestamp on sum(count_cars)

Comment: @Gilly, you trying it on another tables, not on those from the question, right?

Comment: I am using date format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' from a bigger table yes

Comment: I substituted < to_date('2020-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') to sysdate so it will work automatically no matter what the current date is

Comment: I assume change the dataype to date?

Comment: How the "count_cars" col is defined in the bigger table?

Comment: oooh, I guess I can just remove that call, what if it was just counting the dates for sales so that each day that had a sale it would have a count for that day.  Sorry, I thik it just got a bit easier

Comment: select trunc(sale_date), count(*) count_cars from cars1 group by trunc(sale_date)--works

Comment: @Gilly, as long as you don't need to output all the days without any sales, you re good to go without "calendar". However, I think the problem resides in the "cars" tables (or whatever they being called).

Try select sum(count_cars) from XXXX for each of table just to check if there are no error records.

And of course ignore my comments if problem is solved

Comment: thank u for making it clear Ekochergin, you are a master

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222234/discussion-between-ekochergin-and-gilly).